# SQL Query for : rows linked by one joint table INSERT to another joint table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL. In my database I have the following tables:

1. A  `student` table. The primary key of this table is `sid` .
2. A `high_school` table. Primary key is `hid` .
3. A `university` table. Primary key is `uid` .

Then:

- There is a **joint table** for `student` & `high_school`, the table is named `joint_table_A` it has two columns : `sid` and `hid` which link to the rows in `student` & `high_school` respectively.
- There is another **joint table** for `student` & `university` , named `joint_table_B` , it also has two columns : `sid` and `uid` which link to the rows in `student` & `university` respectively.

My problem & question:

I want to have those `students` linked by `sid` in `joint_table_A`  where `hid = 3` being **inserted** to `joint_table_B` and put the value of `uid` to be `1` . That's to have the `sid` in `joint_table_A` where `hid=3` refers to the same students in `student` table as those `sid` in `joint_table_B` with `uid=1`. What is the SQL query for this operation ?

**======== update ==========**

(In above description I assume the `joint_table_B` is empty. However, if in `joint_table_B` there are records for `uid=1`already , then I need to `UPDATE` with those records instead of `INSERT` .)

Comment: I assume, in joint_table_B, you will keep sid same and update uid. Is that correct? or you will keep uid same (which seems wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO joint_table_B (sid, uid)
SELECT students.sid, 1 AS uid FROM students s, joint_table_A a WHERE s.sid=a.sid AND hid=3
```

In case the second table already has rows then use this:

```
INSERT INTO joint_table_B (sid, uid)
SELECT students.sid, 1 AS uid FROM students s, joint_table_A a WHERE s.sid=a.sid AND hid=3 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uid = 1
```

or

```
UPDATE joint_table_B SET uid = 1
WHERE sid IN (select students.sid FROM students s, joint_table_A a WHERE s.sid=a.sid AND hid=3)
```